# @query to get record with max date

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a mysql table called sp_500.  Each record has a unique date.  I want the last record in the table.  It will have the max date.  What is the best query to pull it?  I tried the following HQL:

```
public interface QuoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Quote, Long> {
    
    @Query("from sp_500 a where a.date in (select max(b.date) from sp_500 b)")
    Quote getQuote(String symbol);
}
```

but when I run it, the following error is displayed:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: sp_500 is not
> mapped [from sp_500 a where a.date in (select max(b.date) from sp_500
> b)]

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you add your quote entity?

Comment: @Query(value="select top 1 * from sp_500 order by date desc", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it now compiles.  But when I run it gives "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * from sp_500 order by date desc' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in two ways using the ORDER BY

1)
*Best practice

You can SELECT TOP 1 with the ORDER BY date desc.

Removing the MAX part of you QUERY

//If you are using ORACLE i think is ROW COUNT = 1

2)
You can make the SELECT * ...  ORDER BY date desc
and just grab the first register

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nick and @luisfa19.  You gave me valuable clues.  Here is what worked:

```
@Query(value="select * from sp_500 order by date desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: For Oracle: `@Query(value="select * from sp_500 where date is not null order by date desc fetch first row only", nativeQuery = true)` (the `is not null` is required otherwise null dates appear first).

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
Optional<Quote> findFirstByOrderByDateDesc();
```